# WebDriverWait constructor giving error while declaring public static

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, int) is undefined

```
public static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait( driver, 20);
```

try to declare this WebDriverWait with public static it is giving error
before this I have already declare WebDriver instance

public static WebDriver driver;

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to this and I had the same issue.
It turns out that constructor is deprecated in Selenium 4.
Try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

And call in your code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

This works very well in Selenium 4.